# Switch statement using char from a string with "Error: switch quantity not an integer"

Tags: c++, string, char, switch-statement

In a switch statement for C++, I believe you are allowed to use either int or char in the switch. For my purposes, I want to use a char. The char I want to use is the a char from a string. Here is my function:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
...
int calindex(string* seq)
{
    int index = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<seq.length();i++)
    {
      switch(seq[i])
      {
      ...
      }
    }
return index; // index is modified within the switch statement
}
```

However, when I compile I get an error for the line: "switch(seq[i]" that states "switch quantity not an integer". Can anyone see what I did wrong?

Comment: Well the first error I see is the use of `seq.length()` when `seq` is a pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
switch(seq[i])
```

should be:

```
switch((*seq)[i])
```

You forgot to dereference the pointer first. It's trying to access the ith string. Also:

```
seq.length();
```

should be:

```
seq->length();
```

Answer (score 1):

The case values in a `switch` statement need to be compile-time constant. The point of a `switch` statement is to have a sort of fast, efficient cascading `if` statement. The compiler does special stuff to the switch statement to make it fast, but to do that, it needs to know at compile-time what all of the cases are.

Answer (score 0):

`seq` is a `string *`, not a `char *`, so `seq[i]` has type `string`.

In C++, `string` is preferred over char arrays, and likewise, references are preferred over pointers, so change the declaration of your argument to

```
string &seq
```

so that `string::operator []` can take effect and return a (reference to) `char`.

(You **can** declare `seq` as `char *` too, but then that's C and not C++...)

Answer (score 0):

It is correct to index the string and switch by a char value, but the problem is that you're no indexing a string, but a pointer to a string. Then you should dereference the pointer, but why don't you use a string on the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a string pointer to calindex, but you treat seq as if you passed a string either by value or by reference.

In order to make your switch statement work, you need to dereference the pointer in one of two ways:

```
(*seq)[i]
```

or

```
seq->at(i)
```

Please note that the latter will throw an exception if you try to access a non-existing element, the former won't.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is passing by pointer:

```
int calindex(string* seq)
```

Why dont you use:

```
int calindex(string& seq)
```

Its more safe to do it in that way.

**The most important is that you do not have to make a precondition to check if pointer is zero**

With reference you would not make such a simple mistake like omitting dereferencing.